# rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6) caused by pointer reference

Tags: serial, esp8266, nodemcu

I am experiencing an unusual issue with my code.
I have a **LOLIN WEMOS D1 mini Lite** and I am using the Arduino IDE to upload the sketch.
The version of the board is **3.0.2** for [ESP8266](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.1/).

The problem is with the following line of code:

```
unsigned long n = (this->configuration)->getOffset();
```

There is a class `Aggregator` which has a private member variable named `configuration` which is a pointer to another object of class `Configuration` which is initialized as a global instance. The above line of code is contained in one of the methods of `Aggregator`. Basically, it is trying to access a member getter method of a `Configuration` object and the pointer to this object is set in one of the private members of the `Aggregator` class. This pointer is initialized in the constructor of the `Aggregator` class.

When the code is uploaded, the `Serial` prints out some garbage values and when the `Serial Monitor` of the Arduino IDE is set to `115200` Baud then the output is:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0xcc
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xc9
csum 0xc9
v00052b80
~ld
```

Whenever this line is commented out, the code works fine and the Serial console displays the actual messages and expected lines. It seems that with the above line of code, the board seems to restart in a loop.

Comment: Print out the addresses of `this->configuration` and your global configuration object and see if they match...